# Cannot Print a local html file from webview in Android even if I check for SDK version

Tags: android, printing, android-webview, android-print-framework

I have an html loaded in webview and an ActionBar menu button for start printing.

I click menu button I get the printer dialog box and print. But nothing happens I am using the following for printing html document

```
public void ShowHtml(){
    // Enable Javascript

        WebSettings webSettings = statshtml.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        statshtml.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        statshtml.loadData(str, "text/html; charset=utf-8", "UTF-8");
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_print:

            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
            {
               createWebPrintJob(statshtml);
               return true;
            }


        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
private void createWebPrintJob(WebView webView) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
        return;

    // Get a PrintManager instance
    PrintManager printManager = (PrintManager) getSystemService(Context.PRINT_SERVICE);

    // Get a print adapter instance
    PrintDocumentAdapter printAdapter = webView.createPrintDocumentAdapter();

    // Create a print job with name and adapter instance
    String jobName = getString(R.string.app_name) + " Document";
    printManager.print(jobName, printAdapter, new PrintAttributes.Builder().build());

}
```

What else do I need to print my html? I am testing the app with real device Galaxy Tab 3 and Android version 4.4.2. In which I can print anything else.

Comment: Another way,You can create HTML file and load it to Webview.

Answer (score 0):

```
  statshtml.loadData(str, "text/html; charset=utf-8", "UTF-8");
```

change to

```
 statshtml.loadData(str, "text/html", null);
```

Comment: still nothing happens